# mosquito next to a current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider a long thin plastic covered wire carrying a current. The plastic insulation is positively charged. A mosquito close to the wire wishes to move in such a way that experiences an electric field but no magnetic field. The solution provided uses the Galilean field transformation equations and gives a velocity that is parallel to the current. Is a simpler solution to say that if the mosquito moves in circle centered on the wire it will also experience an electric field but no magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

No, in order for a reference frame to contain only an electric field and no magnetic field, the charges in that reference frame must be stationary. The charges in the wire move along the wire. This is why if you moved along with the charges in the wire (i.e. parallel to the wire), you would measure no magnetic field. A reference frame that's moving in a circle centered on the wire would not see stationary charges. The charges would be moving at a right angle to it. Thus, it would see a magnetic field as well.